# Learning resources - Getting started with development for ArcGis Online

Tags: arcgis-online, development, references, arcgis-runtime-sdk-wpf

I would like to develop [search widget](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/flex-viewer/concepts/index.html#//01m300000038000000) / [find task](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/runtime-wpf/concepts/index.html#/How_to_create_a_Find_task/01700000002w000000/) for feature layer at ArcGis online website.

I would love to get some resources for that (reading links, videos) for getting started. so far i've install SDK WPF and visual studio, I would like to get resources for better understanding of the process ahead.

Comment: I've edited the question

Comment: Are you using ArcGIS Runtime SDK for WPF?  If not, can you review your tags?  If so, can you edit your question to include more details of your research so far into answering your own question?

Comment: is it better now ?

Comment: I'm not a potential answerer of this question.  I think it is too broad and too brief but the GIS software you are using is now clear.

Answer (score 1):

Well, This link can help, is [ArcGIS JS page](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/), it had info and examples.

Some of the examples could be nice for your interest.

Comment: whats the difference between JS and SDK wpf ? and how to Choose the appropriate developing environment ?

Comment: JS is more web/mobile oriented, and WPF is more computer oriented